# Flutter upgrade: ProcessException: Process exited abnormally

Tags: git, flutter, upgrade

When I run `flutter upgrade`, this occur:

```
ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git/': error setting certificate verify locations:  
CAfile: D:/JAY/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt CApath: none
Command: git fetch --tags
```

Why this happens? Also, I don't have Git folder inside D:/JAY. It's inside D:/JAY/Program Files.

Answer (score -2):

Did you check if the .git folder is there in the main folder usually it's hidden. Or maybe you can use

```
cd Program Files
```

and then try to run the command

```
flutter upgrade
```